# Implementing OLS in matrix form

Tags: julia, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I'm having problems implementing this exercise from [a quantitative economics course](https://julia.quantecon.org/index_postgrad.html).

[image: Exercise 3]

Here's my code:

```
N = 50
M = 20

a = 0.1
b = 0.2 
c = 0.5
d = 1.0
σ = 0.1 

estimates = zeros(M, 5)

for i ∈ 1:M
    x₁ = Vector{BigFloat}(randn(N))
    x₂ = Vector{BigFloat}(randn(N))
    w = Vector{BigFloat}(randn(N))
    
    # Derive y vector (element wise operations)
    y = a*x₁ .+ b.*(x₁.^2) .+ c.*x₂ .+ d .+ σ.*w
    
    # Derive X matrix
    X = [x₁ x₁ x₂ fill(d, (N, 1)) w]
    
    # Implementation of the formula β = inv(XᵀX)Xᵀy
    estimates[i, :] = (X'*X)\X'*y
end

histogram(estimates, layout=5, labels=["a", "b", "c", "d", "σ"])
```

I get a `SingularException(5)` error, as the matrix `X'X` has a determinant of 0 and has no inverse. My question is, where have I gone wrong in this exercise? I heard that a reason the determinant might be zero is floating point inaccuracy, so I made the random variables BigFloats to no avail. I know the mistake I'm making isn't very complicated but I'm lost. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you replace `(X'*X)\X'*y` with `X\y`? `\` uses an approach that's better than the normal equations.

Comment: That's a very elegant implementation, I'll be using that from now on! But my issue was solved below. Will post a new question regarding the ```w``` and why it just perfectly returns the original coefficients every time if I can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `X` should be

```
X = [x₁ x₁*x₁ x₂ fill(d, (N, 1))]
```

#### Explanation

It looks that you are trying to test OLS to estimate the parameters of the model:

```
y = α₀ + α₁x₁ + α₁₁x₁² + α₂x₂ + ϵ
```

where  `α₀`, is the intercept of the model, `α₁`, `α₁₁`, `α₂` are parameters for explanatory variables, and `ϵ` is the random error with the expected value `0` and variance `σ²`. Hence the structure of `X` must match your case.

Putting the `α₁` twice you introduced co-linearity and got the error.

You also do not want to "estimate" the parameter for `ϵ` because it represents the randomness.

Comment: Understood, thank you! If we're not supposed to estimate ```σ```, then why does the exercise ask for it? It gave me a much bigger headache than if they just signified error as ```ϵ```.